# Hibernate criteria search on Class(Table) with composite Key

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm trying to get all Database entries for a class which's table is using a composite key.

This is my mapping class:

```
@Entity("MyTable")
public class HBMyTable {
     @Id
     @Column(name = "CategoryID")
     private String categoryId;

     @Id
     @Column(name = "StartpointID")
     private String startpointId;

     ....
}
```

In my Dao i want to use this method to read all entries on the corresponding table:

```
public List<HBMyTable> getAllTableEntries(Session session) {
        Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(HBMyTable.class);
        return criteria.list();
    }
}
```

This will get me results but all startpointIds are null.
The table has 2045 ROWS and all of them are returned in the List
All CategoryIDs are set correctly, but all StartpointIDs are NULL

```
....
HBCategoryStartpoint [categoryId=Workflows, startpointId=null]
HBCategoryStartpoint [categoryId=Workflows, startpointId=null]
HBCategoryStartpoint [categoryId=Workflows, startpointId=null]
FOUND 2045 CATEGORY SP ENTRIES
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution!
To query a table which is using a composite key, you first have to make a Key Class using the @Embeddable annotation

```
@Embeddable
public class CategoryStartpointPK implements Serializable {
    
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1355843364236433447L;
    private String categoryId;
    private String startpointId;

    public CategoryStartpointPK() {}
    
    // getter, setter, toString
}
```

Then in your actual class that maps the table use the Keyclass as Id

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Category_StartPoint")
public class HBCategoryStartpoint implements Serializable {
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5880268624037227966L;
    
    private CategoryStartpointPK categoryStartpointPK;
    
    @Id
    public CategoryStartpointPK getCategoryStartpointPK() {
        return this.categoryStartpointPK;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add a restriction on your query :

```
criteria.add(Restrictions.isNotNull("StartpointID"));
```

And I don't know if you put the annotation `@Entity` before class name

Comment: Thank you for your answer but this did not resolve my problem.
The startpointIDs are not null in the database, none of them is.

Yes I have the @Entity annotation before my class declaration